# How to use qsort for an array of strings?

Tags: c, string, qsort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sortstring(const void *str1, const void *str2) {
    const char *rec1 = str1;
    const char *rec2 = str2;
}

void sortutil(char* lines[]) {
    qsort(lines, 200, sizeof(char), sortstring);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sortutil.h"

int getarray(char *lines[]) {
    int i = 0;
    char *text = (char *)malloc(200);
    while (fgets(text, 200, stdin) != NULL) {
        lines[i] = text;
        i++;
        text = (char *)malloc(200);
    }
    return i;
}

void printarray(char *lines[], int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        printf("%s\n\n", lines[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* arr[100];
    int numlines = getarray(arr);
    printf("There are %d lines\n", numlines);
    printarray(arr, numlines);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc;  i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0) {
            sortutil(arr);
            printarray(arr, numlines);
        }
    }
}
```

When I send in a file with arbitrary text, It'll read the file and print it out, but when i call -s and call the `qsort` function, it comes back with nulls. I'm sure I am using `qsort incorrectly`, what is the right way to use it for an array to char pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your comparator is being sent each pair by-address. I.e. they're pointer-to-pointer-to-char.

Change the comparator to:

```
int sortstring( const void *str1, const void *str2 )
{
    char *const *pp1 = str1;
    char *const *pp2 = str2;
    return strcmp(*pp1, *pp2);
}
```

Likewise, your `sortutil` needs to know the number of items being sorted, as well as pass the correct size of each item. Change that to:

```
void sortutil(char* lines[], int count)
{
    qsort(lines, count, sizeof(*lines), sortstring);
}
```

Finally, the call from `main()` should look like this:

```
sortutil(arr, numlines);
```

That *should* do it.

Comment: thanks that did work, only thing you missed was typecasting str1 and str2 with (const char**)

Comment: @user3427042 actually, I missed the right type in the posted code (duh). It should have been what it is now. Sorry about that. If done correctly, no cast should be needed. Thanks for catching that. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

What the `compar` function gets are pointers to the elements in your array, which in this case, are pointers to `char`. So the parameters `str1` and `str2` are actually pointers to pointers to `char`. You must cast them like this:

```
int sortstring( const void *str1, const void *str2 )
{
    const char *rec1 = *(char**)str1;
    const char *rec2 = *(char**)str2;
    int val = strcmp(rec1, rec2);

    return val;
}
```

Then you have to use the proper element size in `qsort`.

```
qsort(lines, 200, sizeof(char*), sortstring);
```

Comment: It could be because `lines` does not have 200 elements, maybe you can pass `numlines` as a parameter to `sortutil` and use it instead of 200.

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect.

```
    qsort(lines, 200, sizeof(char), sortstring);
```

Change it to

```
    qsort(lines, 200, sizeof(char*), sortstring);
```