# Make linux export function (without arguments) in c (sort bash export output in c)

Tags: c, bash, sorting, export

I'm making a minishell in C. I don't know what is the best way to order the strings. The idea is that by running the C program and typing "export" with no arguments, it simulates the output that bash does (declare -x "text").

How can i order it? Since export in bash orders the output of the env

Thanks

Edit:

I have this for the moment so that I can display it (without ordering), where `g_shell->env` is a global environment variable

```
int i = 0;
while (g_shell->env[i])
{
  printf("%s\n", g_shell->env[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: This has been asked several times this month and the answer is sort them however you want, there is no difference, no one cares.

Comment: What would the code look like? I'm having problems. Or if there is any link from stackoverflow to be able to base myself

Comment: From what I understand, if you give your C program the input "declare -x text", it should store 'text' in the list of variables but in sorted order so that when you do a export, it prints out variables in sorted order. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct, although what I have is a char **, not a list. It would be to order it this way

Comment: You can use `qsort()` inbuilt function to sort an array of strings (`char **`). See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23189704

Comment: I'm testing with this call but it doesn't order it:
sortutil (g_shell->env, sizeof (g_shell->env)
Rest the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23189704

Comment: @Adrian maybe you should update the post with what you have tried and what doesn't work.