# c while turning void type to string getting weird results

Tags: c, qsort

I have a list of words that are separated by empty spaces given by the user input.
I am using qsort to sort them and qsort requires the sorting function to use a void type. While I am trying to change the void type to string and print the results, I get weird characters printed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int compareStrings(const void *x_void, const void *y_void){
    // strings are compared here in lexicographical order
    char *word1 = (char *) &x_void;
    char *word2 = (char *) &y_void;
    printf("%s \n", word1);
    printf("%s \n", word2);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int size;
    // inputs are taken here
    scanf("%d *[^\n]", &size);
    char *sentence = malloc(size + 1);
    fgets(sentence, size + 1, stdin);
    
    int spaceAmount = 0;
    
    // In this loop the amount of space characters are determined.
    findSpaces(sentence);
    
    // The amount of spaces are used to allocate memory for this list of words.
    char **allWords = malloc((spaceAmount + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    int seperator = 0;
    int index = 0;
    
    // allWords list is populated here in this loop with words from the 
    // sentence variable.
    populateAllWords(allWords);
    
    free(sentence);
    qsort(allWords, spaceAmount + 1, sizeof(char*), compareStrings);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < spaceAmount + 1; i++){
        printf("%s \n", allWords[i]);
    }
    
    free(allWords);
    
    return 0;
}
```

here I give input from the console, the size of sentence and the sentence it self. What the code should normally do here is that it should print the words one by one but I am gettin weird results. Here are the console logs:

```
$ ./result.exe
1000
hello I am Tim
─↔y 
└↔y
╚↔y
─↔y
╠↔y
╚↔y
─↔y
└↔y
╚↔y
─↔y
─↔y
└↔y
```

what am I doing wrong? Please help. I added a minimal main function also.

Comment: Please include a minimal main function that triggers this behavior.

Comment: You realize that currently `word1` and `word2` get a **pointer to pointer** of type `void`, right?

Comment: use `x_void` and `y_void` without the ampersand in your `word1` and `word2` initialization

Comment: Your comparison function prints a couple of things then always returns 0. How could that be used as a sensible comparison function in qsort?

Comment: @JohnColeman I removed the rest of the function for clarity sake

Comment: @Bot Ellis The format string in the call of scanf scanf("%d *[^\n]", &size); does not make sense.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189630/how-to-use-qsort-for-an-array-of-strings.
Should be something like `char **word1 = (char **)x_void` and use `*word1` to get the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that callback functions from bsearch/qsort works is that they give you a pointer to an item. With `qsort(allWords,...` you essentially pass an array of pointers. Every item is a pointer, so any pointer passed from `qsort` to your callback will be a pointer to pointer.

`void*` is tricky here since it's the generic object pointer type and you can cast to/from it even when you have a pointer to pointer. (Please note that `void**` is however not such a generic pointer type.)

Therefore your callback should be written as:

```
int compareStrings (const void* obj1, const void* obj2){
    // strings are compared here in lexicographical order
    const char *word1 = *(const char**)obj1;
    const char *word2 = *(const char**)obj2;
    printf("%s \n", word1);
    printf("%s \n", word2);

    return strcmp(word1, word2); // something meaningful not just 0
}
```